# How to bind dynamic column in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview where I am binding this below data where @cols is giving me dynamic dates present in the table.

But how do I bind this column to the gridview as we have to provide the column name in the itemtemplate?

```
WITH cte (startdate)
AS 
(SELECT
    @startdate AS startdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    DATEADD(DD, 1, startdate) AS startdate
    FROM cte
    WHERE startdate < @enddate
)
select c.startdate
into #tempDates
from cte c
where datename(weekday, c.startdate) <> 'Sunday';

SELECT
@cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(CHAR(10),startdate, 105))
    FROM #tempDates
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName,
            D.startdate,
            convert(CHAR(10), startdate, 105) PivotDate
            from #tempDates D,Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
            where convert(CHAR(10), D.startdate, 105) = convert(CHAR(10), A.Date, 105) and A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and A.EnrollmentNo=U.userID
        ) x
       pivot 
       (
            count(startdate)
            for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
       ) p '

       EXECUTE (@query)
```

Gridview-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewAttendance" Style="width: 600px;margin-top:50px; " runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="False" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" PageSize="20" HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" Font-Size="Small" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll No">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRNo" Text='<%# Eval("RollNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("FirstName"), Eval("LastName")) %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="??">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="??" Text='<%# Eval("??") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with BoundField

> Represents a field that is displayed as text in a data-bound control.

First set the property of your Gridview `autogeneratedcolumns=false;`

Try following

```
BoundField testField= new BoundField();
testField.DataField = "New_testField_Name";
test.Headertext = "testField_Header";
CustomersGridView.Columns.Add(test);
```

After discussion with OP.

Just keep your `GridView` without specifying any column.(Apply style and other attributes as per your requirement)

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewAttendance" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="true">


 </asp:GridView>
```

And in `CS` file

Exceute your query and bind results with GridView.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 adp.Fill(dt);

 gridViewAttendance.DataSource = dt;
 gridViewAttendance.DataBind();
```

Simply by doing this, whatever columns your query returns will be displayed in grid.

Comment: The main question is that what do I provide in DataField  as I won't be knowing the column name ?

Comment: From where you will be getting ` @cols` ?

Comment: I have updated the code above. '@cols' will be having the dates.

Comment: Shared.
Actually after displaying name, there should be columns as date (1/1/2018,1/2/2018,.....) .

Comment: Tried that also, doesn't display anything then.

Comment: My bad! 
Autogeneratedcolumns was set to "false".

Comment: Look at last updated answer `<asp:GridView ID="gridViewAttendance" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="true">`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It's displaying data now. Thank you!!

Comment: Please accept answer if it helped you in any way :)